# Step up converter (3.7V to 5V) that will also charge battery!

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

As a picture often speaks better than words, here is what I'm looking for (the yellow circuit on this picture):

[image]

i.e. :

- a circuit that converts 3.7 V to 5 V when a 18650 battery (3.7V) is connected
- and that both **outputs 5 V *and* charges the battery** if a phone charger is connected

Optionnally, it would be great if the circuit could send a "low battery" trigger to some other chip.

Such circuit is probably quite common (in many everyday-use devices that can run in battery or with adapter), do you know where to find one? (either the schematics or even ready-to-use circuits)

Answer (score 3):

Low battery should be easy.  You already have a 5V supply and you're measuring a 3.7V battery, so a comparator between the battery and a voltage divider should do the trick.

As for the boost converter, battery charger, and auto-switch, I would be tempted to skip the auto-switch and always run from the battery, even when charging.  Sure, you're converting 5V to 4.2V (full-charge) and back to 5V again, but it allows you to design a charger and booster almost independently.  Just set the current limit of the charger to cover the application too, but not enough to blow up the battery if the application is off.

While these devices are everywhere, most of them are on the same PCB as the rest of their application, so you may have to roll your own or do some salvaging.  Even if there is one you could buy, asking for that route is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Thanks! Just a question: you say `ow battery should be easy. You already have a 5V supply and you're measuring a 3.7V battery`  : when running on battery alone, we don't have a 5V supply...

Comment: @Basj: Sure you do.  It's your output.  If the output isn't on, then the application isn't powered, and so the indicator doesn't mean much anyway.

Comment: Oh, that's right! Something else: do you have a schematics / part in mind that could do the whole thing?

Comment: @Basj: Search google images for "boost converter schematic" without quotes, and you should get a decent idea for that part.  Change "boost" to "buck" for the charger.  Both types have transistors or switches controlled by poorly defined sources because the source is automatically adjusted according how the output is drifting away from spec.  You can get all the parts to prototype both kinds on a breadboard, and I would recommend a small microcontroller to monitor the circuit via some ADC channels and control the transistors via PWM.  Or you could use an arduino for that job too.

Comment: Make sure you get the level translations right, because there's going to be a lot of them.  You're controlling and monitoring circuits that are likely to be above the voltage rating of the chip itself.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [TI's battery management ICs](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/battery-charger-ic-products.page#).

Some include USB OTG outputs which provide 5V at varying current outputs (you didn't specify power requirements). They will take care of charging your single Li-Ion cell while maintaining the 5V output if an external supply is connected. When the external supply is not connected. the output is supplied from the battery through an internal boost circuit.

It's off-topic to request a single product recommendation, but the general device you're looking for is a battery management IC.

Comment: Thanks! Oh I see 199 matching parts, I'm really a noob about such electronics question and don't want to make a wrong choice, could you give an example of part you'd use?

Comment: @Basj You're going to need to learn at some point if you're going to be building this circuit. I'd suggest you look at the BQ24188 and see if it meets your requirements.

Comment: Thanks @Samuel, so it will work straighforward with just one such chip? No other part required (resistors, capacitors?). What does such a part look like? I saw some schematics, datasheets, but no real photo: will it be SMD or can I try it / prototype it on a breadboard / veroboard? If you were in my situation, in which direction would you go first?

Comment: Sidenote: I want to add this thing to my project http://www.samplerbox.org

Comment: @Basj I'm beginning to suspect this task is beyond your skill level. The IC does not work on its own, external passive components like capacitors, resistors, and inductors are required. The example schematic can be found in the product datasheet. This is a surface mount component, it looks like a little black box smaller than your fingertip. You need to design a PCB to put it on or get a breakout board. If this is all too much you can just [buy a USB battery](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1959) , kludge it inside your case, and be done with it.

Comment: Everything is beyond one's skill level @Samuel, until we learn and we actually do it. Building my own hardware music sampler from scratch was beyond my skill level until a few weeks ago (until I created http://www.samplerbox.org) :)  But I'm really interested for a solution :)

Comment: I already tried to use a USB battery pack like [this one](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1959) but 1/ when you plug in a phone charger, it quickly interrupts the 5V output for a short time, causing my device to shutdown and on again  (that's bad!)   2/ there is no "LOW baterry" information with this solution

Comment: Oh, it's also mentionned [here on the Adafruit page](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1959): `Also, when you start and stop charging the pack, it will flicker the output, this can cause a 'power sensitive' device like the Pi or an iPhone to reset on the power supply`..... Any idea about a solution for that?

Comment: @Basj Excellent attitude, I support that. Moving forward with the charging IC, I suggest getting a SMD breakout board, sometimes called a 'surfboard' or surface mount adapter board. For the BQ24188 you need a QFN24 4mmX4mm adapter, like [this one](http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=2200068). Then you can build the reference design on page 27 of [the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24188.pdf).

Comment: @Basj You might try adding a large decoupling capacitor to coast through that voltage glitch. It will depend on the current draw and the duration of the glitch for what size capacitor you'll need.

Comment: As for why the glitch exists, that's an auto-switch.  The glitch time is how fast it figures out that it's been unplugged and gets the booster online.  Depending on the load, a big cap should work.

Comment: @Samuel / AaronD: A reference about how to use such a capacitor for this purpose? An example circuit? (I'm ready to learn, I just need to find the right examples / tutorials). It's for a Pi, so let's say the glitch lasts 300ms at a load of 600mA / 5V. What kind of cap (+ some resistors?) should I use?

Comment: I=CdV/dt.  With your numbers, 600mA=CdV/300ms.  dV=5V-acceptable_minimum.  Solve for C in Farads and make it slightly bigger to account for some aging and a safety margin.  No resistors, just put it straight across the 5V output.

Comment: @AaronD If you feel like helping for this opensource project, it would be supergreat: http://www.samplerbox.org/article/helpwanted :) Here is a short introduction about it: http://lifehacker.com/build-your-own-midi-sampler-with-a-raspberry-pi-1709318616